# How to get the first name of the logged in User from firebase using Swiftui?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to to get the first name of the current user which is logged in.

This is how my try looks like:

```
 var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
   let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    print(userID)
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      // Get user value
      let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
      let username = value?["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
      print(username)

      // ...
      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: What are u getting?

Comment: i am getting Empty

Comment: Add ur database to the question

Comment: see my update to the question

Comment: The code `ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(` is for the Firebase Realtime Database, while your screenshot and tag show Cloud Firestore. The security rules you're showing apply to Cloud Firestore, while the code you're showing is accessing the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and don't share an API. To access information on Cloud Firestore, use the API documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)
docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
  if let document = document {
    let name = document.get("firstname")
    print("Cached document data: \(name)")
  } else {
    print("Document does not exist in cache")
  }
}
```

You are using cloud firestore but in your code, you are using the Realtime database. You need to check the following docs related to cloud firestore:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: But how to get the first name? I don't need the whole documents

Comment: Did you read the docs? What does the print in the code give you?

Comment: Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

Comment: Check ur security rules and change them to true

Comment: `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks, its working now.  But as I said, I got the whole UIs and first name of all the users, I need just the first name of the logged in user

Comment: To get firstname you need to do `document.get("firstname")`

Comment: You can check the reference here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot

Comment: Could you please update your code? I don't understand the reference correctly :(

Comment: @Alex Did you try the answer?

Comment: Yes the result still nill

Comment: did you print(userId)? because if the document is nil then the userId is either giving u nil or it is not in the firestore database

Comment: with userId, I am getting the correct (current)userid